# AWS IoT-Core Rules Query SELECT Data from MQTT Message (JSON) doubled nested objects Failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot, amazon-timestream

I've been trying to import data from an MQTT message into AWS's Timestream database via a rule for some time. I always get the error

"errorMessage": "Failed to write records to Timestream. The error received was 'Errors at dimensions.1: [Errors at dimensions.2: [Dimension value cannot be empty.], All measures invalid. No record written. Errors: The number of valid records per write should be in [1, 100]...'.

The current query:

`SELECT get(payload, 'streams[0].id') as sensorid, ROUND(get(payload, 'streams[0].value')) as sensordata FROM 'topicname'.`

Tried also:

`SELECT get(get(payload, 'streams'), 0) FROM 'topicname'.`

Does anyone have experience with the SQL statements from AWS Rules? ChatGPT had apparently helped me well, but the error report still says I didn't get any values.

The MQTT Message:

```
{
  "datetime": "2023-06-20T08:49:00Z",
  "payload": {
    "streams": [
      {
        }, "id": { "RS62",
        "value": 885.4801218896597
      },
      {
        }, { "id": "S55",
        "value": 35.89729103822529
      },
      {
        }, { "id": "S56",
        "value": 1.1062225001108246
      },
      {
        }, { "id": "S57",
        "value": 1.9827817232548703
      },
      {
        }, { "id": "S58",
        "value": 1.4765336157706086
      },
      {
        }, { "id": "S59",
        "value": 69.61716498265852
      },
      {
        }, { "id": "S60",
        "value": 75.81964179583608
      },
      {
        }, { "id": "S61",
        "value": 28.12226402898834
      },
      {
        }, { "id": "S62",
        "value": 1491.9799033788302
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance

- I have tried different queries.
- 
- I have googled
- 
- I asked ChatGPT.
- 
- I have written to AWS support and am waiting to hear back.
- 
- I tried to find an online generator or a tool to check the different queries.
- 
- I have enabled the logs, but they don't give any insight to the specific error.
- 
- I also tried it with datetime only, which resulted in success. Therefore, it should basically work, but apparently I'm not reaching the two levels below in the nested object.

Comment: The first "id" at line 6 does not start with `{"id"`. Is this right?

Comment: First, let's address your error message: There is a dimension that is being sent to Timestream API with an empty value. If, for some reason the dimension have an empty value you should omit it from the write request. 
The message also say that all measures are empty, so you're not sending any value at all for any measure. Can you add the expected schema for your timestream record? thanks! :D
Also, you should answer comments with comments, ok? Good luck! :D

Answer (score 0):

thank you for pointing this out. That was indeed an incorrect message. The other messages are all OK and always start with an ID. I have created a rule that brings the result directly in Cloudwatch. Here I can find the values.

> SELECT get(payload.streams, 1).id as sensorid,
> ROUND(get(payload.streams, 1).value) as sensordata FROM
> 'device/topic'.

```
@message    
{"sensorid":"S55","sensordata":37}
@timestamp  
1687337346072
sensordata  
37
sensorid    
S55
```

I dont know why the rule to bring the message into timestream says that I have empty fields.